# Why do we need to delete pointers inside copy assignment operator

Tags: c++, assignment-operator

I have seen several examples of copy assignment operator and could not understand why do we need to delete pointers inside copy assignment operator. For example if I have the following class

```
 class MyClass
 {
  public:
    MyClass(int a)
    {
      x = new int(a);
    }
    MyClass& operator=(const MyClass& pMyClass)
    {
       *x = *(pMyClass.x);

       // ?????????
       // delete x;
       // x = new int(*(pMyClass.x));
    }
    ~MyClass()
    {
       delete x;
    }
  private:
    int* x;
 }
```

What is wrong with *x = *(pMyClass.x) line? I am just copying object pointed by pMyClass.x why I need to delete and create it again?. Could anyone please give example when this code will cause memory leak?

Comment: Your "improvement" is perfectly valid, but then what is the point of `x` being a pointer in the first place?  Typically you see this sort of thing where `x` is pointing to an array, and the old array isn't the right size for the new data.  Then you need to reallocate.

Comment: Store the size of the allocation: `a` then in the copy constructor, allocate that many and "copy" to the newly allocated memory.

Comment: Beyond the obvious (the pointlessness of using pointers for this specific implementation at all) one place what your proposing would *not* work would be for a type that is *not* copy-assignable, but *is* copy-constructible. Obviously `int` doesn't fall into that category.

Answer (score 7):

So this is an example [extracted from Bjarne Stroustrup's "A tour of C++ (2nd edition)] of a copy assignment of a user defined vector class:

```
Vector& Vector::operator=(const Vector& a) // copy assignment
{
double∗ p = new double[a.sz];
for (int i=0; i!=a.sz; ++i)
p[i] = a.elem[i];
delete[] elem; // delete old elements
elem = p; // here elem is the vector's data holding member array
sz = a.sz;
return ∗this;
}
```

To understand why at line 6 we have the deletion operation:

```
delete[] elem; // delete old elements
```

we first need to first understand the distinction between copy constructor and copy assignment. In the first case (copy constructor) we create a completely new object, whereas in the second case (copy assignment, the one we're actually interested in) we already have an existing object into which we just want to copy the contents of another given object of the same type.

Given the fact that we already have an existing object, we first need to clear it's contents so that we are then able to copy the desired content from the object we intent to copy.

I hope that answers your question.

Answer (score 0):

It is a valid code. But if instead of the pointer to a single object you will have a pointer to first element of an array and arrays may have different sizes then you need to delete the array that to reallocate it with the new size.

Answer (score 0):

Nothing wrong with `*x = *(pMyClass.x)` when you copying value from one class instance to other. I think, in general, deleting an object (if it is not just `int`) can prevent usage of new object with new data if before `operator=` execution address stored in `x` was sent to some other part of program.